# create nested hash from a list

Tags: ruby, hash

I have got a list `l = [:foo, :bar, :baz]` and want to assign a varible into a hash `h ={}` programmatically.

Hash should look like

```
{ foo: { bar: { baz: some_value } } }
```

**Note:** the keys are variables!

#### Question:

1. How can I do this?

Comment: Start with showing what have you already tried.

Comment: You need a value for those future keys.

Comment: What should `h` look like?

Comment: @mudasobwa when I have no idea how to do it, how can I show it, genius?! :/

Comment: @EricDuminil `h` should look like: `h = { foo: { bar: { baz: some_value } } }`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko because I a tree of elements, hash is suitable fo my purpose, speed wise!

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) on the reversed list :

```
l = [:foo, :bar, :baz]
h = l.reverse.inject(:some_value) do |value, key|
  { key => value }
end
p h
# {:foo=>{:bar=>{:baz=>:some_value}}}
```

[`reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse) is used in order to build the innermost hash first, and keep building the nested hash outwards.

Comment: `eval input.inspect.gsub(/\s*,\s*/, '=>{').gsub(/[\[\]]/, {'[' => '{', ']' => "=>:some_value#{'}'*input.size}"})` :)